# dplyr: Aggregate continuous datetime

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with million os rows. I have two datetime columns that indicate a certain interval that a device has been working. After some corrections I got the result as shown in the following dataframe.

```
data <- data.frame(id = 1:9,
               Device = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","B","B"),
               Chanell = c("111","111","111","111","333","111","222","333","333"),
               StartSession = c("2021-12-01  01:56:49","2021-12-01  03:02:50","2021-12-01  07:57:10","2021-12-01  09:03:11","2021-12-01  00:35:00","2021-12-01  05:00:00","2021-12-01  04:07:00","2021-12-01  06:15:00","2021-12-02  07:45:00"),
               EndSession = c("2021-12-01  03:02:50","2021-12-01  07:57:10","2021-12-01  09:03:11","2021-12-01  13:12:16","2021-12-01  01:45:00","2021-12-01  06:30:00","2021-12-01  09:15:00","2021-12-01  07:10:00","2021-12-01  08:22:00"))



data$StartSession <- as.POSIXct(datateste5$StartSession,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
data$EndSession <- as.POSIXct(datateste5$EndSession,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

data

```
  Device    Chanell       StartSession           EndSession
             <chr>       <S3: POSIXct>         <S3: POSIXct>
1   A         111      2021-12-01 01:56:49  2021-12-01 03:02:50
2   A         111      2021-12-01 03:02:50  2021-12-01 07:57:10
3   A         111      2021-12-01 07:57:10  2021-12-01 09:03:11
4   A         111      2021-12-01 09:03:11  2021-12-01 13:12:16
5   B         333      2021-12-01 00:35:00  2021-12-01 01:45:00
6   B         111      2021-12-01 05:00:00  2021-12-01 06:30:00
7   C         222      2021-12-01 04:07:00  2021-12-01 09:15:00
8   B         333      2021-12-01 06:15:00  2021-12-01 07:10:00
9   B         333      2021-12-02 07:45:00  2021-12-01 08:22:00
```

Now, I needed to aggregate sessions when the device is the same, chanell and there is a continuity in datetime

I tried somehow to consider NA, whenever there was continuity. The idea was to make a final filter that excluded these cases. The problem is that I don't know how to replace the EndSession value with the last line.

This is my tentative:

```
datanew <- data %>%
       arrange(Device, StartSession) %>% 
       mutate(StartSessionC2 = ifelse((Device == lag(Device) & Chanell == lag(Chanell) & StartSession == lag(EndSession)),NA,StartSession),
              EndSessionC2 = ifelse((Device == lag(Device) & Chanell == lag(Chanell) & StartSession == lag(EndSession)),NA,EndSession)) %>%
       transform (StartSessionC2 = as.POSIXct(StartSessionC2, origin='1970-01-01'), 
                  EndSessionC2 = as.POSIXct(EndSessionC2, origin='1970-01-01')) %>%

        mutate(TuneDurationC2 = EndSessionC2-StartSessionC2,
               StartSessionC2 = replace(StartSessionC2,1,as.POSIXct(StartSession)),
               EndSessionC2 = replace(EndSessionC2,1,as.POSIXct(EndSession)))
```

datanew

This is my expected result:

```
      Device    Chanell       StartSessionC2        EndSessionC2        
                 <chr>       <S3: POSIXct>         <S3: POSIXct>               
    1   A         111      2021-12-01 01:56:49  2021-12-01 13:12:16   
    2   A         111              NA                     NA
    3   A         111              NA                     NA
    4   A         111              NA                     NA
    5   B         333      2021-12-01 00:35:00  2021-12-01 01:45:00   
    6   B         111      2021-12-01 05:00:00  2021-12-01 06:30:00   
    7   C         222      2021-12-01 04:07:00  2021-12-01 09:15:00   
    8   B         333      2021-12-01 06:15:00  2021-12-01 07:10:00   
    9   B         333      2021-12-02 07:45:00  2021-12-01 08:22:00
```

the final solution may not contain the NA lines

Comment: "The idea was to make a final filter that excluded these cases".  *Including* rows with `NA` actually makes the problem harder.  Are you willing to accept a solution that exludes them?  That is, one which returns only rows 1, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 of your expected output?

Comment: yes of course...this was just my failed attempt :)

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Device, Chanell) %>%
  summarize(StartSession = min(StartSession), EndSession = max(EndSession))
```

Resulting to:

```
  Device Chanell StartSession        EndSession         
  <chr>  <chr>   <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 A      111     2021-12-01 01:56:49 2021-12-01 13:12:16
2 B      111     2021-12-01 05:00:00 2021-12-01 06:30:00
3 B      333     2021-12-01 00:35:00 2021-12-01 08:22:00
4 C      222     2021-12-01 04:07:00 2021-12-01 09:15:00
```

Edit: after re-reading your question I realize you might want to have the B 333 split since there is time between the EndSession and the StartSession of the next. Not a problem, we can achieve that like so:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Device, Chanell) %>%
  arrange(StartSession) %>%
  mutate(index = c(0, cumsum(lead(StartSession) > EndSession)[-n()])) %>%
  group_by(Device, Chanell, index) %>%
  summarize(StartSession = min(StartSession), EndSession = max(EndSession)) %>%
  select(-index)
```

Resulting to:

```
  Device Chanell StartSession        EndSession         
  <chr>  <chr>   <dttm>              <dttm>             
1 A      111     2021-12-01 01:56:49 2021-12-01 13:12:16
2 B      111     2021-12-01 05:00:00 2021-12-01 06:30:00
3 B      333     2021-12-01 00:35:00 2021-12-01 01:45:00
4 B      333     2021-12-01 06:15:00 2021-12-01 07:10:00
5 B      333     2021-12-02 07:45:00 2021-12-01 08:22:00
6 C      222     2021-12-01 04:07:00 2021-12-01 09:15:00
```

Comment: I think the second solution is precisely what I'm looking for. I'm trying to test it, but it's hard to run the script. If possible, could you leave just a brief explanation of how the cumsum function works in this context. Thank you so much

Comment: So inside the cumsum you see lead(start) > end. This checks (TRUE/FALSE) if the start time of the next item (within the group) is bigger than the end time of the current item. The cumsum then creates a unique index for each item in the same group that should not be aggregated together (hence index is put in the following group_by).

Comment: the c(0, ...)[-n()] is then used to replace all the NA values with 0 and have the cumsum start at 0

Comment: I wish you all the best! thank you very much once again

Comment: If you found this answer useful please checkmark it :)

Comment: Hi @Wietse finally had some time to run the code today. It takes a few hours to run! But that's not the problem. The problem is that it is not returning the expected result. Probably   my example didn't catch all possible cases and maybe I didn't specify enough. I'm not getting to the solution. (I think it's too advanced for my level). Do I edit this or create a new question? I hope you can help me

Comment: I made i new post in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68425477/dplyr-aggregate-continuous-datetime-with-conditions

Comment: Hello again @user15926848 . Could you edit the original question with an example of an output (if possible also the related input) of where the result is not as you had expected? I can then try to adapt that in my answer