# dplyr: Aggregate continuous datetime with conditions

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I have a dataframe with million os rows. I have two datetime columns that indicate a certain interval that a device has been working. After some corrections I got the result as shown in the following dataframe.

```
data2 <- data.frame(id = 1:9,
               Device = c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B"),
               Chanell = c("111","111","111","111","111","111","111","333","333"),
               StartSession = c("2020-12-06 22:03:45","2020-12-06 22:10:07","2020-12-27 22:47:00","2020-12-31 15:06:02","2020-12-31 22:04:12","2020-12-31 23:16:05","2020-12-31 23:46:05","2021-01-02 00:29:05","2021-01-03 22:02:04"),
               EndSession = c("2020-12-06 22:10:07","2020-12-06 22:29:49","2020-12-27 23:53:09","2020-12-31 15:18:03","2020-12-31 22:19:14","2020-12-31 23:46:05","2021-01-01 00:06:00","2021-01-02 00:38:05","2021-01-03 23:08:07"))

data2$StartSession <- as.POSIXct(data2$StartSession,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
data2$EndSession <- as.POSIXct(data2$EndSession,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

data2

id Device  Chanell       StartSession           EndSession
1   A      111     2020-12-06 22:03:45    2020-12-06 22:10:07
2   A      111     2020-12-06 22:10:07    2020-12-06 22:29:49
3   A      111     2020-12-27 22:47:00    2020-12-27 23:53:09
4   A      111     2020-12-31 15:06:02    2020-12-31 15:18:03
5   A      111     2020-12-31 22:04:12    2020-12-31 22:19:14
6   A      111     2020-12-31 23:16:05    2020-12-31 23:46:05
7   A      111     2020-12-31 23:46:05    2021-01-01 00:06:00
8   B      333     2021-01-02 00:29:05    2021-01-02 00:38:05
9   B      333     2021-01-03 22:02:04    2021-01-03 23:08:07
```

Each row represents a Device session, in a given chanell and during an interval of time

After making the necessary corrections, i found the following problem: When a device has two or more continuous sessions on the same channel, then the information should be aggregated in a single session

For the example above, this is my expected result:

```
id Device  Chanell       StartSession           EndSession
1   A       111     2020-12-06 22:03:45     2020-12-06 22:29:49
3   A       111     2020-12-27 22:47:00     2020-12-27 23:53:09
4   A       111     2020-12-31 15:06:02     2020-12-31 15:18:03
5   A       111     2020-12-31 22:04:12     2020-12-31 22:19:14
6   A       111     2020-12-31 23:16:05     2021-01-01 00:06:00
7   B       333     2021-01-02 00:29:05     2021-01-02 00:38:05
8   B       333     2021-01-03 22:02:04     2021-01-03 23:08:07
```

Only 4 sessions from Device A should be affected as they are the only ones that are continuous (EndSession1 = StartSession2) and Chanell is the same for both sessions

I had already posted a question on the topic here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68407210/15926848

but unfortunately after testing the real problem i realized that i wasn't getting the intended answer. Unfortunately, I couldn't change it to get the expected result.

By the way, should I delete the other post?

tks in advance

Comment: Why row 6 and 7 are merged into one but not row 1 and 2?

Comment: You're right. My mistake. I will correct

Comment: If the answer from your previous post is used on the dataset shared in this post it gives the expected output as shown.  Did you check that? If that answer doesn't help on your actual dataset you should precisely provide an example where the previous answer fails to get a better improved version of the answer.

Comment: Hi Ronak you are absolutely right. In fact the solution seems to me to be correct. I just didn't mark it as valid, because unfortunately given the size of my original dataset (millions of rows), the solution doesn't work. It has been running all day and unfortunately does not return results. ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `data.table` option for faster processing -

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data2)[, group := cumsum(StartSession - shift(EndSession, fill = 0) > 0), .(Device, Chanell)]

data2[, .(id = first(id),
          StartSession = min(StartSession), 
          EndSession = max(EndSession)), .(Device, Chanell, group)]

#   Device Chanell group id        StartSession          EndSession
#1:      A     111     1  1 2020-12-06 22:03:45 2020-12-06 22:29:49
#2:      A     111     2  3 2020-12-27 22:47:00 2020-12-27 23:53:09
#3:      A     111     3  4 2020-12-31 15:06:02 2020-12-31 15:18:03
#4:      A     111     4  5 2020-12-31 22:04:12 2020-12-31 22:19:14
#5:      A     111     5  6 2020-12-31 23:16:05 2021-01-01 00:06:00
#6:      B     333     1  8 2021-01-02 00:29:05 2021-01-02 00:38:05
#7:      B     333     2  9 2021-01-03 22:02:04 2021-01-03 23:08:07
```

Comment: whowwww!! Magic! I wish I could dominate the same as you!! I have no idea what you did, but it did work and it got the result in less than 5 min! I really have to study data.tables... I have no idea what it means! I rely a lot on dplyr to do everything! Formidable @Ronak. Hope to have your help in more situations! eheheh

Answer (score 3):

My attempt

```
dat <- data2 %>% 
  group_by(Device, Chanell) %>% 
  mutate(time_diff = (StartSession) - lag(EndSession, 1)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Find the differences for each channel and device between the end of the previous session and the start of the new one.

```
ind.same.date <- which(dat$time_diff == 0)
dat$StartSession[ind.same.date] <- dat$StartSession[ind.same.date - 1]
```

If the difference is zero then overwrite the previous start session.

```
dat <- dat %>% 
  slice(-c(ind.same.date - 1)) %>% 
  select(-time_diff)
```

Remove unnecessary rows and column.

```
# A tibble: 7 x 5
     id Device Chanell StartSession        EndSession         
  <int> <chr>  <chr>   <dttm>              <dttm>             
1     2 A      111     2020-12-06 22:03:45 2020-12-06 22:29:49
2     3 A      111     2020-12-27 22:47:00 2020-12-27 23:53:09
3     4 A      111     2020-12-31 15:06:02 2020-12-31 15:18:03
4     5 A      111     2020-12-31 22:04:12 2020-12-31 22:19:14
5     7 A      111     2020-12-31 23:16:05 2021-01-01 00:06:00
6     8 B      333     2021-01-02 00:29:05 2021-01-02 00:38:05
7     9 B      333     2021-01-03 22:02:04 2021-01-03 23:08:07
```

Comment: Hi @Kozolovska your solution seems to me to be entirely correct, unfortunately I'm not succeeding, because the dataset size is too big. As I said above, it has been running all day and it doesn't return the result.